# converting an array of characters to a const gchar*

Tags: c, gtk

I've got an array of characters which contains a string:

```
char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
buf[0] = 'f';
buf[1] = 'o';
buf[2] = 'o';
buf[3] = '\0';
```

I'm looking to pass this string as an argument to the `gtk_text_buffer_insert` function in order to insert it into a `GtkTextBuffer`. What I can't figure out is how to convert it to a `const gchar *`, which is what `gtk_text_buffer_insert` expects as its third argument.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gchar` is just a `typedef` for `char` and the conversion from arrays to const pointers is implicit, so you can just pass it:

```
someFunctionExpectingConstGcharPointer(buf);
```

Note that you can also directly initialize arrays with string literals:

```
char buf[MAXBUFLEN] = "foo";
```

Comment: I would add, there is no reason to ever use the "gchar" typedef. It's used in GTK+ itself for historical reasons (consistency, since nobody wants to do a giant search-and-replace). But don't use it in apps. gchar is defined to just be char. Same for gint, gdouble, etc. they are just defined to be the same as int and double.

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets see. [GTK+ reference manual](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-insert) says:

> gtk_text_buffer_insert ()
>
> void                gtk_text_buffer_insert              (GtkTextBuffer *buffer,
>                                                            GtkTextIter *iter,
>                                                            **const gchar *text**,
>                                                            gint len);
>
> Inserts len bytes of text at position iter. If len is -1, text must be nul-terminated and will be inserted in its entirety. Emits the "insert-text" signal; insertion actually occurs in the default handler for the signal. iter is invalidated when insertion occurs (because the buffer contents change), but the default signal handler revalidates it to point to the end of the inserted text.
>
> buffer : a GtkTextBuffer
>   iter :    a position in the buffer
>   **text : UTF-8 format text to insert**
>   len :     length of text in bytes, or -1

and

> [gchar](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-Basic-Types.html#gchar)
>   typedef char   gchar; 
>   **Corresponds to the standard C char type**

This means, that a char* can be used in place of gchar*.

Though I have not used gtk_text_buffer_insert() , but in other gtk+ functions that require gchar*, char* has worked flawlessly.

Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This may be really late, but in case anyone else stuck with this comes here with a google:

```
gtk_text_buffer_insert(GTK_TEXT_BUFFER(textbuffer),&iter,buffer,strlen(buffer));
```

should do the trick. The problem is the null character on the end. So by sending in the string length you send in all characters before the null character.

Comment: There's no need for the strlen; glib/gtk APIs that take a string length almost always allow "-1" which means "it's nul-terminated, strlen it for me" - so you could use -1 here.