# GTK+, gchar in struct seems to be deallocated

Tags: c, struct, gtk

In my Application I have struct:

```
struct
{
  gchar *xen_srv_addr;
  gchar *xen_srv_usr;
  gchar *xen_srv_psw;
  gchar *xen_srv_prt;
} Xen_Server_Connection;
```

I want to assign a values to that gchars. I read it from file, parse with strtok and return as a char*.
Setting parser looks for specific tokens and:

```
if(a==b)
  {
    Xen_Server_Connection.xen_srv_addr=Parm_Pars(pattern, 2);
    .....
  }
```

This assignment works only inside this if block.
gchar became garbage just after it. But if I:

```
if(a==b)
  {
    Xen_Server_Connection.xen_srv_addr="192.168.1.1";
    .....
  }
```

All seems ok and I can access to that gchar globally.
Seems I don't understand something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't understand what lifetime guarantees the `Parm_Pars()` function gives on the returned value. It seems it doesn't live forever, so you need to duplicate it if you want to hang on to it.

Simply wrap that line in a call to `g_strdup()` to get a dynamically allocated copy and you should be fine. Of course, when you want to free your `Xen_Server_Connection`, you must call `g_free()` on all duplicated strings or you will leak memory.

*UPDATE*: Mixing plain `char` and `gchar` is fine, glib guarantees that `gchar` is just an alias for `char`. I think they even recommend (somewhere) that applications never use `gchar`.

Comment: Oh, such a silly mistake. Thanks a lot! Just one more question. In this case is it good at all to mix char and gchars in one code?

Comment: @unwind You read it here on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800310/converting-an-array-of-characters-to-a-const-gchar/2800318#2800318